# PHPDoc: Typehint in nested arrays (with e.g. 2 dimensions)

Tags: php, arrays, phpdoc, code-documentation

Is there a correct way to document values/objects in arrays which are within another dimension?

Normally an array will be handled like this:

```php
/** @var ClassName[] $Array */
$Array = array( $InstanceOfClassName,.. )
```

But i need something like this:

```php
/** @var ClassName[][] $Array */
$Array = array( 0 => array( $InstanceOfClassName,.. ) )
```

This is obviously not working, so what is the correct PHPDoc notation?

Comment: Note: My IDE is PhpStorm.. maybe there is a specific solution? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, understand that this usage of @var is not standard phpDocumentor spec.  It is one of several *different* ways that different IDEs have tried to make "autocompletion for local variables" possible.  I know that Eclipse uses the format `/* @var $varName \ClassName */`.  So keep that in mind as other answers/suggestions come in.

The only way I can see to leverage this IDE autocompletion hack with your two dimensional array is to use another @var later on when you are *reading* the first dimension out, though this does require that to go into a variable itself:

```
/* @var $outer array */
$outer = array( 0 => array($InstanceOfClassName,...));

/* @var $inner ClassName[] */
$inner = $outer[0];
```

`$inner[0]->` *(expect autocompletion of ClassName methods here)*

Now again, how useful this can be for autocompletion depends on how your IDE has built it.  Some IDEs might know that ClassName[] syntax and deduce that an element pulled from $inner is a ClassName, and therefore it can show its methods.  However, I cannot say I've seen *any* IDE do that yet.  At most, it's been a stretch to see IDEs simply have the @var hack available in its most basic form (`/* @var $var ClassName */`).

TL;DR:  Your mileage may vary in just trying to get half of what you're after :-)

Comment: Iam not sure about what is "standard" in phpDoc, but it's [supported](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/var.html) .. on the other hand, [there is](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/types.html) no information about multiple dimensions can be handled :-( .. so i'am left with your solution then :-) .. and it works for me.. thank you ;-)

Comment: var tag -- https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

types -- https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html

Answer (score 29):

PhpStorm allows to typehint nested arrays with double brackets [][]:

```
/** @var \SplFileInfo[][] $doubleNestedArray */
$doubleNestedArray = [[]];

$doubleNestedArray[0][1]->getFileInfo(); // ->getFileInfo() is suggested by IDE
```

Comment: In PhpStorm you can also specify multiple types using a pipeline delimiter EG: `@var \Traversable|array[]|\SplFileInfo[][]|string[][] $doubleNestedArray`

Comment: This is great! You can add more nesting, too - e.g. @var array[][][][] $myArray

Comment: It's worthy to note, though, that PHPDoc will output this as a single dimension array (\SplFileInfo[]). In my opinion, accurate inline doc and IDE completion are far more useful than accurate generated doc output, so that's still a very helpful trick.