# PHP 7 Arrays - Detection of property of an element of a 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, phpdoc

I want my PHP IDE (NuSphere PhpEd) to detect a property of my 2D array element ( an object ) whose property is not showing up after I type a right arrow in my IDE.

**Is there any way in PHP 7 to auto generate suggestions of a multidimensional array element properties where each element is an object with certain properties?**

```
<?php
    class Cell
    {
        private $color;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->color = "red";
        }

        public function __get($propertyName)
        {
            if ($propertyName == 'color')
                return $this->color;
        }

        public function __set($propertyName, $value)
        {
            if ($propertyName == 'color')
                $this->color = $value;         
        }
    }

    class Matrix implements ArrayAccess
    {
        private $matrix = array();

        public function __construct($maxX, $maxY)
        { 
            $this->matrix = array_fill(1, $maxX, array_fill(1, $maxY, null));
        }

        public function &offsetGet($name)
        {
            return $this->matrix[$name];
        }

        public function offsetSet($name, $value) 
        {
            $this->matrix[$name] = $value;
        }

        public function offsetExists($name)
        {
            return isset($this->matrix[$name]);
        }

        public function offsetUnset($name)
        {
            unset($this->matrix[$name]);
        }
    }


    $matrix = new Matrix(3,3);
    for ($xIdx = 1; $xIdx <= 3; $xIdx++)
       for ($yIdx = 1; $yIdx <= 3; $yIdx++)
            $matrix[$xIdx][$yIdx] = new Cell();

    $matrix[2][2]->color = "green";
    echo $matrix[2][2]->color;
?>
```

Comment: You're moving into the realm of phpdoc, which is a technology that does allow you to provision that type of information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  would you by chance have an example of how I can see that in phpdoc suggested properties list when I type the arrow?

Comment: Of course, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to use phpdoc annotations, you can use the `Type[][]` annotation to declare a variable as being a 2D array of `Type`. In the case of a class property that looks like:

```
/** @var Cell[][] */
private $matrix = [];
```

Or for the return value of a class method:

```
/**
 * @return Cell[][]
 */
public function getMatrix() {
    return $this->matrix;
}
```

In the case of PHPStorm, that provides this:

[image]

Comment: Thank You! This sounds similar to something I tried accomplishing in the past.  I believe I might have crossed this bridge before.    I take it there is no other way like in the language directly to get out the property?

Comment: @Vahe Unfortunately from what I can see, even top-tier IDEs like PHPStorm do not infer this information on their own and require the guidance of phpdoc.

Comment: For some reason I could not get the property to display as a suggestion, after arrow, before I typed the property name.    I placed the phpdoc annotation on top of offsetGet().

Comment: @Vahe Your IDE may have lower phpdoc support. I've added a screenshot of how PHPStorm behaves with the annotation.

Comment: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543050/phpdoc-typehint-in-nested-arrays-with-e-g-2-dimensions   but I can't seem to make it work with PhpEd

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround in order to force phpdoc to pick up my property or method following the arrow.

Here is what I did.

```
class Matrix
{
     protected $maxX;
     protected $maxY;

     private $matrix = array();

     public function __construct($maxX, $maxY)
     {
         $this->maxX = $maxX;
         $this->maxY = $maxY;

         $this->matrix = array_fill(1, $maxX, array_fill(1, $maxY, 0));
         return $this;
     }

     public function getMaxX()
     {
        return $this->maxX;
     }

     public function getMaxY()
     {
        return $this->maxY;
     }

     public function get($x, $y)
     {
        if (isset($this->matrix[$x][$y]))
            return $this->matrix[$x][$y];
        throw new OutOfBoundsException("Array at indices $x, $y is out of bounds!");
     }
}

class Main
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function setArrayVal($x, $y)
    {
         $cell = new Cell();
         //Set Value in some arbitrary method in Main Class
         $this->matrix($x, $y)->set($cell);
         //Or if $val is public in Cell class
         // $this->matrix($x, $y)->val = $cell;
    }
    //Method of Main Class
    public function matrix($x, $y) : Cell  //Note Cell here specified for type hinting
    {
        //Note, matrix below is a property, not method, whose type corresponds to the matrix class
        return $this->matrix->set($x, $y);
    }
}

class Cell
{
     private $val;

     public function __construct()
     {

     }

     // Method set in Cell class
     public function set($val)
     {
        $this->val = $val;
     }
}
```